# cmake and deb dependencies

Tags: cmake, deb

Suppose I have a CMake project with `exectuable A` and shared `library B`. Library B is also dependent of the `crypto` library, and links to it dynamically. `Library B` is also *publicly* dependent of `crypto` (maybe it uses a function from there in a header file). This is easy to express in CMake as a transitive (public) dependency, so that `crypto` dependency does not need to be specified for `executable A`.

However, I would also like to to have the possibility to alternatively have `library B` built as a Debian dev package, install it in a known location and link to it from CMake when building `executable A`. The CMake info about the transitative dependency is thereby lost (that is, that I also have to link to `libcrypto`). What is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: The trick is to export `library B`.  There's an example in the duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks @StephenNewell it seems this is what I want to do, if I also supply the finpackage file with the debian package!